# Vue.js: A value in a v-for loop is not staying with the correct array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am trying to create a simple application to request a car key for a service department. Obviously the code could be written better, but this is my third day with Vue.js. The time function that is called in the first p tag in the code updates every minutes to keep count of an elapsed time. The problem I am having is when I request a new key the time function doesn't follow the array items as intended. For example, if there are no other requests the first request I submit works perfectly. However, when I submit a new request the elapsed time from my first request goes to my second request. I am sure it could have something to do with the glued together code, but I have tried everything I can think of. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-md-6" v-for="(key, index) in keys" :key="index">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Service Tag: {{ key.service_tag }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text"> {{time}} {{key.reqTimestamp}}min</p>
            <p class="invisible">{{ start(key.reqTimestamp) }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Associates Name: {{key.requestor_name}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Model: {{key.model}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Color: {{key.color}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Year: {{key.year}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Comments: {{key.comments}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Valet: {{key.valet}}</p>
            <input class="form-control" v-model="key.valet" placeholder="Name of the person getting the car...">
            <button
              @click="claimedKey(key.id, key.valet)"
              type="submit" 
              class="btn btn-primary"
              >Claim</button>
              <button v-if="key.valet !== 'Unclaimed'"
              @click="unclaimedKey(key.id, key.valet)"
              type="submit" 
              class="btn btn-primary"
              >Unclaim</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" @click="complete(key.id)">Complete</button>
          </div>
      </div>
<!-- END OF CARD -->
<!-- START OF FORM -->
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center request">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          <h1 class="display-4">Operation Tiger Teeth</h1>
          <form class="form-inline" @submit="newKey(service_tag, requestor_name, comments, model, year, color, valet, reqTimestamp)">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="service_tag">Service Tag: </label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="service_tag" placeholder="ex: TB1234">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="service_tag">Associates Name: </label>
              <!-- <input class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="requestor_name" placeholder="Your name goes here..."> -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
                <select v-model="requestor_name" class="form-control" id="requestor_name">
                  <option>James Shiflett</option>
                  <option>Austin Hughes</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="service_tag">Model: </label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="model" placeholder="What is the model of the vehicle?">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="service_tag">Color: </label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="color" placeholder="What is the color of the vehicle?">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="service_tag">Year: </label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="year" placeholder="What year is the car?">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="service_tag">Comments: </label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="comments" placeholder="Place any additional comments here...">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 invisible">
              <label for="service_tag">Valet: </label>
              <input v-model="valet">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 invisible">
              <label for="service_tag">Timestamp: </label>
              <input v-model="reqTimestamp">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Request A Key</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "../main";
import { setInterval } from 'timers';
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      keys: [],
      reqTimestamp: this.newDate(),
      service_tag: "",
      requestor_name: "",
      comments: "",
      color: "",
      model: "",
      year: "",
      inputValet: true,
      valet: "Unclaimed",
      state: "started",
      startTime: '',
      currentTime: Date.now(),
      interval: null,
    };
  },
  firestore() {
    return {
      keys: db.collection("keyRequests").where("completion", "==", "Incomplete")
    };
  },
  methods: {
    newKey(service_tag, requestor_name, comments, model, year, color, valet, reqTimestamp, completion) {
      // <-- and here
      db.collection("keyRequests").add({
        service_tag,
        requestor_name,
        comments,
        color,
        model,
        year,
        valet,
        reqTimestamp,
        completion: "Incomplete",
      });
      this.service_tag = "";
      this.requestor_name = "";
      this.comments = "";
      this.color = "";
      this.model = "";
      this.year = "";
      this.reqTimestamp = this.newDate()
    },
      complete(id) {
        db.collection("keyRequests").doc(id).update({
          completion: "Complete"
        })
      },
    // deleteKey(id) {
    //   db.collection("keyRequests")
    //     .doc(id)
    //     .delete();
    claimedKey(id, valet) {
      console.log(id);
      this.inputValet = false
      db.collection("keyRequests").doc(id).update({
        valet: valet,
        claimTimestamp: new Date()
      })
    },
    moment: function () {
    return moment();
    },
    newDate () {
      var today = new Date()
      return today
    },
    updateCurrentTime: function() {
      if (this.$data.state == "started") {
          this.currentTime = Date.now();
        }
      },
      start(timestamp) {
        return this.startTime = timestamp.seconds * 1000
      }      
    },
  mounted: function () {
            this.interval = setInterval(this.updateCurrentTime, 1000);
  },
  destroyed: function() {
            clearInterval(this.interval)
  },
  computed: {
    time: function() {
      return Math.floor((this.currentTime - this.startTime) /60000);
    }
  }
  }
</script>
```

Ideally I am looking for the time lapse to follow each request.

Comment: "the time function doesn't follow the array items as intended" --- can you elaborate which part of the code this is about?

Comment: Basically, I never see keys:[] being changed. So... there's that.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have the computed time property that is called in the paragraph tag to for lack of a better term stick to the array elements in that loop iteration. That way the proper elapsed time is with the right data.

Comment: the keys array is where I am calling in my database (firestore)

Comment: I don't see the `firestore` method being called

Comment: It is right underneath the data property. Sorry for placing so much code in the code block. Seeing as the code isn't the cleanest I figured I could be doing something wrong anywhere.

Comment: No, I see the method. I don't see how you're calling it (i.e. `firestore()`) or how `keys` is updated still (i.e. `this.keys = await firestore().keys`)

Comment: Not 100% on where I pulled this from, but it works on getting my data into the vue app

Comment: ```firestore() {
    return {
      keys: db.collection("keyRequests").where("completion", "==", "Incomplete")
    };
  }```

Comment: Okay sorry it's a firebase syntax that I wasn't aware of what it was doing

Comment: Why is `this.reqTimestamp = this.newDate()` after `db.collection("keyRequests").add({...})`?

Comment: Adds a timestamp into the database of when the key was requested. Best way I could think to do it.

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't you set that before you submit the `.add()` request?

Comment: Oh, you're resetting the values... kinda?

Comment: I swapped it and it still works...trust me, I believe I have gotten this far in spite of myself. The elapsed time clock is the biggest headache. Also I am sure there are bits of code that don't need to be in there...trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem lines in the template are:

```html
<p class="card-text"> {{time}} {{key.reqTimestamp}}min</p>
<p class="invisible">{{ start(key.reqTimestamp) }}</p>
```

The call to `start` has side-effects, which is a major no-no for rendering a component. In this case it changes the value of `startTime`, which in turn causes `time` to change. I'm a little surprised this isn't triggering the infinite rendering recursion warning...

Instead we should just use the relevant data for the current iteration item, which you've called `key`. I'd introduce a method that calculates the elapsed time given a `key`:

```js
methods: {
  elapsedTime (key) {
    const timestamp = key.reqTimestamp;
    const startTime = timestamp.seconds * 1000;

    return Math.floor((this.currentTime - startTime) / 60000);
  }
}
```

You'll notice this combines aspects of the functions `start` and `time`. Importantly it doesn't modify anything on `this`.

Then you can call it from within your template:

```html
<p class="card-text"> {{elapsedTime(key)}} {{key.reqTimestamp}}min</p>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for the help and the explanation from where I went wrong!

Comment: So I just hosted this on github.io to quickly test and when the request is submitted on one device the time stamp is right. When you view that request on another device (my phone) the timestamp says -13 min. Any ideas?